# Cómo utilizar la API de Foursquare correctamente?

Tags: python, api

acutalmente estoy realizando un trabajo de geolocalización,y quiero usar la API de Foursquare para buscar pubs.Estoy utilizando esto,pero no me funciona.Quiero que me devuelva todos los starbucks que estén en esa zona.

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search'
params = dict(
    Client_Id=os.getenv("clientID"),
    Client_Secret=os.getenv("clientSecret"),
    ll='1.316764, 103.899039',
    query="Starbucks",
    limit=1000,
)
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)

data1=json.loads(resp.text)
```

Recibo este error:

```
{'meta': {'code': 400,
  'errorType': 'invalid_auth',
  'errorDetail': 'Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication for details.',
  'requestId': '5efa419195d86421fc118cee'},
 'response': {}}
```

Comment: Publica tu código, explica como/donde está fallando, muestra el mensaje de error (si lo hay) y toda la información relevante. Los links no son gratos.

Comment: ¿Puedes imprimir Client_Id y Client_Secret antes de enviarlos? Solo para que confirmes que están correctos, no para publicarlos aqui.

Comment: si hago `print(Client_Id) me dice que no está definido

Comment: Tienes que hacer print(params['Client_Id']) inmediatamente antes de ejecutar request.get(). Lo mismo con Client_Secret

Comment: Me da None,no entiendo que pasa tengo creado un archivo .env y está dentro de .gitignore para que no se suba a github.Dentro esta clientID=''

Comment: Parece que os.getenv("clientID") no recupera las credenciales correctas, y por lo tanto foursquares te niega el acceso. Haz la prueba colocando directamente las credenciales en el diccionario. Si eso funciona, tu problema es 'os.getenv("clientID")', no foursquare.

Comment: Nada,sigue sin funcionar ni cuando meto el código que se genera directamente en foursquare.Puede tener algo que ver con que el Pilgrim SKD esté disabled??

Answer (score -1):

Parece que tienes un problema con las variables de ambiente.

Yo uso Linux, y la cosa funciona asi:

En el terminal, escribo:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects$ export Client_Id="Candid Moe"
```

Eso establece una variable de ambiente que está disponible para cualquier programa que ejecute a posteriori.

Tengo este simple programa:

```
import os

print(os.getenv("Client_Id"))
```

Al ejecutarlo, produce el siguiente resultado:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects$ python3 env.py 
Candid Moe
```

Al parecer en Window las variables de ambiente se fijan de manera distinta. Alguna otra persona podría publicar el procedimiento adecuado.

Mientras no fijes este problema, nada más va a funcionar.

Comment: Tu respuesta no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, el OP está preguntando por el uso de una API.

Comment: @gcoronel99. El problema es que no tiene puesta las variables de ambiente. Esa es la respuesta.

Comment: @gcoronel99. Y si revisas la siguiente pregunta del mismo usuario, verás que si era la solución al problema. Ahora ya no tiene este mensaje de error.

Comment: Sabes que es una API al menos? Ese problema se genera por no tener las credenciales necesarias, **proporcionadas por la API**.